# Error Analysis on two different sized data sets

Tags: regression, python, standard-error

Here the situation. I have a model plane that records velocity in the x, y, and z axis at 16hz. I have a small data recorder attached to the underbelly of the plane that is also recording the same velocity at 1hz. I "flew" the plane in simulated turbulence for 3 hours and collected data. I want to validate the error of the data recorder by plotting the error using the formula:
$$
\epsilon = \frac{|Ax_n-Dx_n|}{Ax_n} * 100\% $$
Where $Ax = \text{Aircraft Velocity} \ and \ Dx = \text{Recorder Velocity} $

At every second $n$.

The problem is I have 16hz of data for the airplane and 1hz for the data recorder so there is a huge discrepancy between the amount of data points I have. I am not sure what to do if I average all the data points I have for every second for the airplane there are huge errors. I know these errors don't exist because if I plot them ontop of each other there's only very small discrepancies. My research professor wants me to use error though so I am not sure what to do. **BONUS** if anyone know show to do this in python pandas or numpy.

Comment: I was lost at the formula, because by definition the "velocity" in three dimensions is a *vector* but it makes no sense to divide a real number by a vector.  Maybe you're recording a *speed*?  And if so, why is the *relative* speed of such interest?  To the extent speeds get slow, that ratio will suffer by exaggerating errors at low speeds. Could you be more specific about the "huge errors" that arise from averages?  That's unexpected and needs some description so we can understand what you're doing.

Comment: I was going to graph the direction of each velocity x,y,z errors on their own I was just using one direction as an example. Am i just really dumb and forgetting all these things from school?

Also regarding the errors, there's a lot turbulence so as an example so even within 1 second the 16hz recorder is getting numbers that range from -5m/s to 5m/s and everything in between while the 1hz gives a 4.25ms. If I ave those 16 bits of data at that 1 second for the 16hz recorder I will get like 1.3 something which then = over 100% error.

Comment: It is important to describe your data correctly and fully in the question.  Coordinates differ from velocities and speeds; and there are relationships among the coordinates (the sum of their squares equals the speed); and the nature and magnitude of the variations in measurements you experience might be key to suggesting solutions.  It would help to exhibit a typical (but small) subset of your data, too.